# Need to create Oracle ODBC

Tags: oracle, odbc, tnsnames

I am trying to create new ODBC for oracle,my sqlnet.ora file contains below code.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,LDAP)

Which file i need to modify first sqlnet.ora or tnsnames file before creating ODBC ?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF192). I think you only need to touch the tnsnames.ora file and it should work.

Comment: In below sample syntax for tnsnames.ora  SERVICE_NAME and SID needs to be updated.From where i can find SERVICE_NAME and SID details of oracle server.                           
                                                                               
                                                                               
  SERVICE_NAME.world =   
  (DESCRIPTION =    
    (ADDRESS_LIST =    
        (ADDRESS =    
        (protocol adapter information)    
        )    
    )    
    (CONNECT_DATA =    
      (SID = SID)
        )   
  )